# Node GCM with proxy - port 443 disabled

Tags: android, node.js, proxy, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I am using the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm

It works fine with port 443 enabled without any proxy set up. But I need it to work in an RHEL environment with 443 disabled.

Node GCM plugin behind a proxy. Below is the code

```
var message = new gcm.Message();

            // ... or some given values 
            var message = new gcm.Message({
              collapseKey: 'demo',
              priority: 'high',
              contentAvailable: true,
              delayWhileIdle: true,
              //timeToLive: 10000,
              restrictedPackageName: '',
              dryRun: false
            });


            var notification_title = config_file.gcm.gcm_title ? config_file.gcm.gcm_title.replace(/\\'/g,"'") : '';
            var message_content = config_file.gcm.gcm_content ? config_file.gcm.gcm_content.replace(/\\'/g,"'") : '';
            // as object 
            message.addNotification({
                title: notification_title,
                body: '',
                icon: 'notification',
                tag: false,
                sound: true
            });



            // Set up the sender with you API key 
            var requestOptions = {
                proxy: 'http://aws-public-ip:8000',
                timeout: 1000
                // strictSSL: false,
                // method: 'POST'
            };
            var sender = new gcm.Sender(config_file.gcm.gcm_api, requestOptions);

            // Add the registration tokens of the devices you want to send to 
            var tokens = [];
            for(var t = 0; t < token.length; t++)
            {
                tokens.push(token[t].gcm_token);
            }

            // Max devices per request    
            var batchLimit = 1000;

            // Batches will be added to this array
            var tokenBatches = [];

            // Traverse tokens and split them up into batches of 1,000 devices each  
            for ( var start = 0; start < tokens.length; start += batchLimit )
            {
                // Get next 1,000 tokens
                var slicedTokens = tokens.splice(start, start + batchLimit);

                // Add to batches array
                tokenBatches.push(slicedTokens);
            }
            // You can now send a push to each batch of devices, in parallel, using the caolan/async library
            async.each( tokenBatches, function( batch, callback )
            {
                // Assuming you already set up the sender and message
                sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: batch }, function(err, response) {  

                    // Push failed?
                    if (err)
                    {
                        // Stops executing other batches
                        console.log('ds');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('ts');
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                    // Done with batch
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function( err )
            {
                // Log the error to console
                if ( err )
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

Also I have enabled the outgoing port for 8000. Also below commands to enable the proxy in aws and npm

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://aws-public-ip:8000"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://aws-public-ip:8000"
export NO_PROXY="169.254.169.254"
export http_proxy="http://aws-public-ip:8000"
export https_proxy="http://aws-public-ip:8000"
export no_proxy="169.254.169.254"
npm config set proxy http://aws-public-ip:8000
npm config set https-proxy http://aws-public-ip:8000
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
sudo npm config set proxy http://aws-public-ip:8000 -g
```

I get the error `{ [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }`

TL DR: I'm not sure if I have set the proxy in aws correctly with the above commands. Also, I am not sure if the plugin will work with 443 port being disabled.

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake. The proxy address should have been a correct ip, which accepts proxy and has connection to 443 port open.

I was using the same ip of aws as proxy not knowing what proxy really is.

I created another instance in aws with ubuntu OS and installed tiny proxy. Opened required ports and provided the new instance ip as proxy in the my app and it works.